# Color the column of a latex table produced by xtable

Tags: r, latex, sweave

How can I use the R xtable package to produce a table with a colored column? [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-to-create-coloured-tables-with-sweave-and-xtable) post shows how to color a row, but I can't figure out how to do the same for columns.

Comment: You'd have to add this to the table's column specification. See [How do I color table columns and rows?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94799/5764) for a pure LaTeX way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snipped that should clarify it. The key is to define a new column type. In this example Iused "a" for the name of the new column and assigned a medium gray to it:

```
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}


<<xtable1, results=tex, echo=F>>=
xtab<-xtable(d, caption="...", label="tab.myData")
align(xtab) <- c('l', 'c', 'a')
print(xtab, floating=F, include.rownames = F)
@
```